# Apache solr : append extra fields to result of heatmap faceting(2d array)

Tags: solr

I'm doing the clustering of travellers using facet_heatmaps which returns the counts in a 2d integer array, and then I plot them all in a map using Esri.

Each traveller has a location type, ranging from 1 to 6, and each value within that range, has a matching icon on the map.

If cluster's count > 1 it will always be the same icon because it's a group, however, if cluster's count == 1, it means that I have to display the traveller with the icon matching his location type.

The problem is that I have no way to know which location type has that traveller got, because heatmap_faceting only returns an array with the counts for each cluster.

Do you see any way or workaround to get location type field added to the result ? I don't think there's a way to add more fields to that array, so I don't see any solution :(

Comment: Could you do a second query with the areas that only have single hits?

Comment: I could, but it means i would have to do another query with all coordinates x and y(of clusters having count=1), in parameters of the query. That coul be a lot of data. Then, in the ui, i would have to compare cluster coordinates, with the response of the second query, to set the right location type.

Comment: Now let's say i need to know which travellers are contained in a cluster of 10 people? How would identify them ?

Comment: Then you're not really talking about faceting, but grouping/collapsing. You might be able to achieve that by using multiple `{frange}` as a `group.queries`. No idea about the performance (which I would assume would be bad, since it'll have to return _many_ documents. In cases like this it's usually better to retrieve all the documents and allow your frontend to do clustering.

Comment: Not sure to understand your answer.. i'm using facet.heatmap so i'm talking about faceting. Why would i cluster 1000 000 documents on the UI?

Comment: Is there a way to query the result of facet heatmap ?

Comment: I think i was wrong in the answer i gave you.  I need to know for each cluster that heatmap has returned the location type if cluster = 1 and the travellers contained in that cluster. How can i achieve that ? Is there a way to modify the facet heatmap response ?

Comment: My point is that faceting is "given me the count of documents for `<term>`". You're asking about getting the documents (give me the documents that would be in each of these buckets) that match within each bucket, which isn't a faceting operation - but a grouping / collapsing operation. Querying the result of a facet is done by applying a `fq` with the filter that generated the facet (the term, or in this case, the bbox). In your case I'd take the list of facets that only have one hit, generate a query for those coordinates and then return those documents assigned to each bbox.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to technically querying the result of facet heatmap. "Querying the result of a facet is done by applying a fq with the filter that generated the facet" Could you give me an example ? 
This is how my query looks:
fq={!collapse field=traveler_id min=ms(NOW,start_time)}&facet=on&facet.heatmap=lat_lon&wt=json&facet.heatmap.gridLevel=3&facet.heatmap.geom=["-180 -90" TO "180 90"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168583/discussion-between-jaybe78-and-matslindh).